# Allow characters in Taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Does anybody know how to allow characters such as commas, slashes, hyphens,etc into a taxonomy term. I created a custom taxonomy and would like to input a term like "abc,123" but it currently splits the term into two. Anybody know of a filter to allow characters? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to add the taxonomy? are you using a custom script? Using the wordpress 3.6 backend should accept your "abc,123". If you are using custom code, please feel free to share it.

Comment: No custom code. Yes this is WordPress 3.6 and using "abc,123" WordPress actually splits it into two terms "abc" and "123"

Answer (score 0):

that is wp doing that, so you can add multiple terms in one hit, but yes you can have commas, though not recommended. the [bulkpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulkpress/) will let you, but this plugin comes up with error in wp 3.6+, but still adds term

Comment: Thanks. I will need to dig into the plugin and see what is being used. Thank you for your input.